# Does there exist injective ring homomorphism between given rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Does there exist injective ring homomorphisms?

$1.$ ${\bf Z}[x] \to M_n(\bf Z)$

$2.$ $\dfrac{{\bf Z}[x]}{(f(x))} \rightarrow  M_n (\bf Z)$ where $\deg f(x)=n$.

Comment: Consider the image of $x$ in any ring homomorphism.  What does the characteristic polynomial of that matrix tell us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As you were told, this is not possible since the image of $X$ is a matrix which always satisfies a polynomial equation.
2. Let $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ be *monic* with $\deg f=n$. Then we can define an injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[X]/(f)\to M_n(\mathbb Z)$ as follows: send $X$ to $C_f$, the companion matrix of $f$. Since the minimal polynomial of $C_f$ is $f$, the kernel of the map is $(f)$.

If $f$ is not monic, then this can be wrong: there is no injective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z[X]/(2X+2)$ to $\mathbb Z$ since the first is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, observe that by Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, every matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial. This would force $X$ to be algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$.